# Could not type any text inside textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

I am using redux-form-material-ui for my form. With below code, i cannot type anything on the textfield. I mean to say nothing gets type in the textfield. There are two textfield in my form and one Autocomplete. One is for device name and another for timeout value. Autocomplete works though. Why is it not showing the text i have typed?

What might be the reason for this issue? Have i done somewhere mistake?

Please see an image attached. I cant write anything in device name and timeout input box. Only autocomplete box can be selected and is shown on input box.

[image]

**Here is my code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

import {
    AutoComplete as MUIAutoComplete, MenuItem,
    FlatButton, RaisedButton,
 } from 'material-ui';

import {
  AutoComplete,
  TextField
} from 'redux-form-material-ui';

const validate = values => {
  const errors = {};
  const requiredFields = ['deviceName', 'deviceIcon', 'deviceTimeout'];
  requiredFields.forEach(field => {
    if (!values[field]) {
      errors[field] = 'Required';
    }
});
  return errors;
};

class DeviceName extends Component {

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.handleNext();
  }

  render() {
      const {
          handleSubmit,
          fetchIcon,
          stepIndex,
          handlePrev,
          pristine,
          submitting
      } = this.props;
    return (
        <div className="device-name-form">
            <form>
                <div>
                    <Field   
                        name="deviceName"
                        component={TextField} {/* cannot type */}
                        floatingLabelStyle={{ color: '#1ab394' }}
                        hintText="Device Name"
                        onChange={(e) => this.setState({ deviceName: e.target.name })}
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Field
                        name="deviceIcon"
                        component={AutoComplete} {/* works */}
                        hintText="icon"
                        openOnFocus
                        filter={MUIAutoComplete.fuzzyFilter}
                        className="autocomplete"
                        dataSource={listOfIcon}
                        onNewRequest={(e) => { this.setState({ deviceIcon: e.id }); }}
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Field
                        name="deviceTimeout"
                        component={TextField} {/* cannot type */}
                        floatingLabelStyle={{ color: '#1ab394' }}
                        hintText="Device Timeout"
                        ref="deviceTimeout" withRef
                        onChange={(e) => this.setState({ deviceTimeout: e.target.name })}
                    />
                </div>
                <div style={{ marginTop: 12 }}>
                  <RaisedButton
                    label={stepIndex === 4 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
                    primary
                    disabled={pristine || submitting}
                    className="our-btn"
                    onTouchTap={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
                  />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ fetchIcon }) => ({
    fetchIcon
});

const DeviceForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'DeviceForm',
  validate,
})(DeviceName);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DeviceForm);
```

Comment: Please clarify the text field that is not working and provide a more minimal case of your problem. It will help people to analyse your code. regards

Comment: Can you use `setState()` in React without first initialising the state?

Comment: yes it can be. I have used like this in adding other data and its working. We can do it that way too if we dont want to show the initial state in the form.

Comment: OK, why are you setting the state if you are later not using its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can simplify your form as-

```
class DeviceName extends Component {

  handleSubmit = (values) => {
      console.log(values); // Do something with values
  }

  render() {
      const {
          ....
          handleSubmit //***Change 
      } = this.props;
    return (
        <div className="device-name-form">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit)}>
                <div>
                    <Field   
                        name="deviceName"
                        component={TextField} {/* cannot type */}
                        floatingLabelStyle={{ color: '#1ab394' }}
                        hintText="Device Name"
                        //*** line removed
                    />
                </div>
                .....
                .....
                <div style={{ marginTop: 12 }}>
                  <RaisedButton
                    type="submit" // setting type
                    label={stepIndex === 4 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
                    primary
                    disabled={pristine || submitting}
                    className="our-btn"
                  />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This works. Removing onChange event works. I found out that we cannot select item twice in Autocomplete so i moved to redux-form instead of redux-form-material-ui. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

By adding `onChange` to your `Field`s, aren't you preventing redux form from accepting the new values from that input field? Is there a reason you are attempting to add these to your Component state?

The examples in the documentation certainly suggest you should not need to do this - http://redux-form.com/6.1.1/examples/material-ui/

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the problem is in your onChange handlers - you probably need to use `target.value` rather than `target.name`:

```
onChange={(e) => this.setState({ deviceTimeout: e.target.value})
```

Comment: My problem is i cannot type any text in input field.

Comment: Sorry still not working. I can't type anything in input field yet.

Comment: I have updated my question. You can see there the input box has no text because i cannot write anything there. Only autocomplete input box is working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, turned out I used the wrong import. I was using the normal import:

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
```

Because my store is immutable (using Immutable.js) I had to use the immutable import:

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form/immutable'
```

Some kind of error logging for redux-form would have been handy in this case.